# ASP.NET Event Calendar Null Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I tried this tuto [ASP.NET Event Calendar for DHTMLX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBWHMDNCUp8)
with VS2013 usinf ASP.net MVC 4 Web Application

**BasicSchedulerController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DHTMLX.Scheduler;
using DHTMLX.Common;
using DHTMLX.Scheduler.Data;
using ScheduleEvents.Models;


namespace ScheduleEvents.Controllers
{
    public class BasicSchedulerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);
            scheduler.Data.Loader.PreventCache();
            scheduler.LoadData = true;
            scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;
            return View(scheduler);
        }

        public ActionResult Data()
        {
            return new SchedulerAjaxData(new SampleDataContext().Events);
        }

        public ActionResult Save(Event updatedEvent, FormCollection formData)
        {
            var action = new DataAction(formData);
            var context = new SampleDataContext();

            try
            {
                switch (action.Type)
                {
                    case DataActionTypes.Delete:
                        {
                            updatedEvent = context.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.idevent == updatedEvent.idevent);
                            context.Events.DeleteOnSubmit(updatedEvent);
                        }
                        break;
                    case DataActionTypes.Error:
                        break;
                    case DataActionTypes.Insert:
                        context.Events.InsertOnSubmit(updatedEvent);
                        break;
                    case DataActionTypes.Update:
                        {
                            updatedEvent = context.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.idevent == updatedEvent.idevent);
                            UpdateModel(updatedEvent);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                context.SubmitChanges();
                action.TargetId = updatedEvent.idevent;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                action.Type = DataActionTypes.Error;
            }

            return new AjaxSaveResponse(action);
        }

    }
}
```

But the problem when I want to insert new event, it will be Null, also the table data is Null

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should sign `Save` as `[HttpPost]`, shouldn't you?

Comment: did you even try it?

Comment: yes I add it but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Do you get nulls for all columns or some specific ones?

There may be a couple of reasons

```
public ActionResult Save(Event updatedEvent, FormCollection formData)
```

The Event object is parsed from the request values using Model Binding mechanism of MVC, it depends on locale set in your system.

There may be an issue if the server is not in Invariant Culture settings - by default scheduler uses this format for stringifying the dates before sending them to the server. When scheduler's and server's formats mismatch dates will be parsed incorrectly and you may get nulls.
Probable solution would be to use **DHXEventsHelper** for parsing the request values, as shown here
http://scheduler-net.com/docs/managing-crud-operations.html#update_method

2) Can you please show the declaration of the Event model? 
On the video it is done on [2:16](https://youtu.be/gBWHMDNCUp8?t=2m16s%202:16).
Client-side requires a fixed names for a mandatory properties (**id, text, start_date, end_date**, as shown in video), if you named them differently - by default scheduler won't bind these properties.

You can either rename properties of your model class or configure mappings using **DHXJsonAttribute**
http://scheduler-net.com/docs/loading-data.html#custom_names_for_data_properties

If none of this helps - please upload your project somewhere and give a download link, so I could check it locally

Comment: this my project, u will find a winforms aand  wcf, but u need the asp : http://www.mediafire.com/download/kp7dysvyzeug1sd/ScheduleEvents.rar